# Why is this ifelse statement producing NAs?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable based on other variables in my dataset. I have used ifelse to do similar tasks, however when I have tried it this time I am getting NA when the condition is not met.

The variables I want to base the new variable on are all binary - "Yes" or "No". I want to the new variable to be coded "Yes" if any of the other variables are "Yes" and "No" if none of them are coded "Yes". When I run the ifelse, I get the expected number of "Yes", but what I would expect to be "No" is NA.

I have tried the following:

```
data$new <- ifelse(var1=="Yes" | var2=="Yes" | var3=="Yes","Yes","No")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have changed the names of the data and put three variables in the example. There are actually 22 variables in total with very similar names, I tried to simplify the example. If seeing the actual data / code would be helpful I'll add this in.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be because you have `NA` elements i either one of the 'var's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `==` returns `NA` if there is any NA.  An option would be to `cbind` the variables 'var1', 'var2', 'var3' (not clear if it is a data.frame column or independent vectors), compare with `"Yes"`, to create a logical matrix, use `rowSums` to get the sum of 'Yes' strings.  Note the `na.rm = TRUE`  which would take care of the `NA` elements (if any).  Using the row sums, check the value is greater than 0, then it is "Yes" or else "No"

```
ifelse(rowSums(cbind(var1, var2, var3)== "Yes"), na.rm = TRUE) > 0, "Yes", "No")
```

---

To check why it is producing `NA`

```
v1 <- c("Yes", "No", NA)
v2 <- c("No", NA, "Yes")

(v1 == "Yes")|(v2 == "Yes")
#[1] TRUE   NA TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. I thought I had already dealt with missing data, but turns out I hadn't. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try complete.cases() to omit NA's while creating the variable

```
df$new <- ifelse((var1 =="Yes"| var2=="Yes"|var3=="Yes")& complete.cases(df), "Yes", "No")
```